# unable to get the image from kinect on turtlebot

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

-i tried to run the roslaunch turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch but i received this errors:
... logging to /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/892cff36-d0c4-11e1-a96f-94dbc938c889/roslaunch-turtlebot-laptop-23710.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://10.61.130.54:57086/

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /kinect_laser/max_height
- /openni_camera/depth_rgb_rotation
- /rosdistro
- /openni_camera/image_mode
- /openni_camera/image_time_offset
- /openni_camera/projector_depth_baseline
- /kinect_laser_narrow/output_frame_id
- /openni_camera/depth_mode
- /kinect_laser_narrow/max_height
- /openni_camera/depth_frame_id
- /openni_camera/depth_time_offset
- /kinect_laser/output_frame_id
- /rosversion
- /openni_camera/depth_registration
- /openni_camera/debayering
- /openni_camera/depth_rgb_translation
- /kinect_laser/min_height
- /pointcloud_throttle/max_rate
- /openni_camera/shift_offset
- /kinect_laser_narrow/min_height
- /openni_camera/rgb_frame_id

NODES
/
kinect_breaker_enabler (turtlebot_node/kinect_breaker_enabler.py)
openni_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
openni_camera (nodelet/nodelet)
pointcloud_throttle (nodelet/nodelet)
kinect_laser (nodelet/nodelet)
kinect_laser_narrow (nodelet/nodelet)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [23724]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.61.130.54:11311

setting /run_id to 892cff36-d0c4-11e1-a96f-94dbc938c889
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [23737]
started core service [/rosout]
process[kinect_breaker_enabler-2]: started with pid [23749]
process[openni_manager-3]: started with pid [23750]
process[openni_camera-4]: started with pid [23751]
process[pointcloud_throttle-5]: started with pid [23752]
process[kinect_laser-6]: started with pid [23753]
process[kinect_laser_narrow-7]: started with pid [23755]

[ERROR] [1342607835.267919792]: Failed to load nodelet [/pointcloud_throttle] of type [pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/turtlebot/pointcloud_to_laserscan/lib/libcloud_to_scan.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1342607835.300934504]: Service call failed!

[pointcloud_throttle-5] process has died [pid 23752, exit code 255].
log files: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/892cff36-d0c4-11e1-a96f-94dbc938c889/pointcloud_throttle-5*.log
respawning...
[pointcloud_throttle-5] restarting process
process[pointcloud_throttle-5]: started with pid [23863]

[ERROR] [1342607836.239323946]: Failed to load nodelet [/openni_camera] of type [openni_camera/OpenNINodelet]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_camera/lib/libopenni_nodelet.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1342607836.265996116]: Service call failed!

[openni_camera-4] process has died [pid 23751, exit code 255].
log files: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/892cff36-d0c4-11e1-a96f-94dbc938c889/openni_camera-4*.log
respawning...
[openni_camera-4] restarting process
process[openni_camera-4]: started with pid [23888]

[ERROR] [1342607837.069661136]: Failed to load nodelet [/kinect_laser] of type [pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/turtlebot/pointcloud_to_laserscan/lib/libcloud_to_scan.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1342607837.100921720]: Service call failed!
[kinect_laser-6] process has died [pid 23753, exit code 255].
log files: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/892cff36-d0c4-11e1-a96f-94dbc938c889/kinect_laser-6*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser-6] restarting process
process[kinect_laser-6]: started with pid [23911]

[ERROR] [1342607837.904375912]: Failed to load nodelet [/kinect_laser_narrow] of type [pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/turtlebot/pointcloud_to_laserscan/lib/libcloud_to_scan.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1342607837.923636130]: Service call failed!
[kinect_laser_narrow-7] process has died [pid 23755, exit code 255].
log files: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/892cff36-d0c4-11e1-a96f-94dbc938c889/kinect_laser_narrow-7*.log
respawning...

does anyone knows what  would be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39115/unable-to-get-the-image-from-kinect-on-turtlebot/) by [MBN](https://answers.ros.org/users/2846/mbn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-07-18**:
Do you have the kinect plugged into the USB 3.0 port? For some reason, it works best there.

**Comment by [dougbot01](https://answers.ros.org/users/2842/dougbot01/) on 2012-07-18**:
I think it might be better if you reference your previous question, or stay on that thread, so people will know what things you've already tried. Please indicate what things you've changed http://answers.ros.org/question/38991/no-device-connected-turtlebot-kinect/

**Comment by [MBN](https://answers.ros.org/users/2846/mbn/) on 2012-07-18**:
dougbot01 I have two robots working on, and the problem solved for this one i'm going to post the answer.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-07-19**:
Please post this log for me: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/892cff36-d0c4-11e1-a96f-94dbc938c889/pointcloud_throttle-5*.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try to install libmysqlclient16, it worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [MBN](https://answers.ros.org/users/2846/mbn/) with karma: 18 on 2012-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0